# Country Name Correction - Magento 2.0.1

Tags: magento2, checkout, country-regions

In checkout page I need to change country list. I can achieve this from admin side. **Store->Configuration->General->General->Conutry Options**. I have chosen **India** only but the frontend show **Inde**. Where could I change Inde to India?
[image: easy for your reference]

I need to change Inde to India

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inde is India on French. Probably your store has french language, but anyway you can fix translates in csv files (folders i18n). Just search Inde in *.csv and replace it to you variant.